# Error: invalid 'length' argument in executing for-loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

After running the second loop below I keep receiving an error:

```
Error in integer(n) : invalid 'length' argument
```

I am almost certain this worked with no modifications before, I struggle to find reason why this error appears. Any help will be appreciated.

```
mv <- c(0,1,2)  # location vector
s <- 1          # scale
increment <- seq(-6,6,0.01)             # Create a sequence of x values
y=matrix(0,length(increment),length(mv))

for (i in 1:length(increment)) {
        for (j in 1:length(mv)) {
                y[i,j] <- 1/(1+ exp(-(increment[i]-mv[j])/s))
        }
}

# Create matrices:
valuematrix <- vector("list",ncol(y))

for (i in 1:ncol(y)) {
        newmatrix <- replicate(rep,y[,i])
        valuematrix[[i]] <- newmatrix
}
```

Comment: `rep` is undefined in the `replicate`

Comment: I have voted to close as a typo

Comment: That first loop is ugly: Consider this improvement: `y <- outer(increment, mv, function(x,y){ 
                  1/(1+ exp(-(x-y)/s))
         })`